# JS Particles - Cross instead of Circle

Tags: javascript

I'm using the .js particle ground demo available here: http://jnicol.github.io/particleground/

I've managed to get rid of the lines and just display the dots, however, I would like to change the dots to be crosses, the plus symbol +.

I've isolated the following bit of code that draws the circle here:

```
Particle.prototype.draw = function() {
      // Draw circle
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.position.x + this.parallaxOffsetX, this.position.y + this.parallaxOffsetY, options.particleRadius / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill();
}
```

But I can't figure out how ti either make it draw a cross or to replace the circle with the plus character +

Many thanks...

Comment: Line 4 in your example is responsible for drawing the circle. Like you can see, it draws an arc. You will need to figure out how to path a cross, and replace the `ctx.arc()` call.

Comment: Hi - I understand where it is... and I understand I need to replace it. That's exactly my question - What do I replace it with??

Comment: In that case, your question is "How can I draw/path a cross?" and not "How do I replace a circle with a cross?". I suggest you read about [the 2d canvas context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D), especially the part about drawing rectangles (a cross is two rectangles layered on one another).

Comment: I would like to know how I replace the circle with a cross - Anyway - thank you for the resource I do appreciate it however - I am not fluent in javascript so I'm looking for help on how I can do it exactly. Someone to show me so I can learn.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a code request site, rather a help site to get help with specific things you're stuck on. I agree with Madara, I would first start with trying to draw a cross and go from there. If you're stuck, just ask what code you're stuck on.

Comment: Here's a start: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Javascript/Canvas_How_to/Shape/Draw_cross_lines.htm

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I'm looking for... a little help to point me in the right direction and someone to explain so I have a starting point. I assumed it was a simple bit of code - I'm not trying to request code - if you ask someone here how to do something in css they often tell you what to try, not just tell you to go and learn css... but I was unaware that there was more to it. More people need to be patient with learners that's why we're here, to learn. Thanks again :)